# MOP: acess any slot definition ? (mito's col-type)

Tags: common-lisp, clos, mop

I define a class which uses the Mito ORM, the slots define a `:col-type`:

```
(isbn
 :accessor isbn
 :initarg :isbn
 :col-type (or (:varchar 128) :null))
```

How to get the `:col-type` definition ? Since this is a slot in my class definition, is there no generic way to access it, like `slot-definition :col-type ...` ?

On the [clos-mop documentation](http://metamodular.com/CLOS-MOP/readers-for-slot-definition-metaobjects.html), I only find how to access

```
slot-definition-allocation
slot-definition-initargs
slot-definition-initform
slot-definition-initfunction
slot-definition-name
slot-definition-type
```

The isbn slot shows like this:

```
#<MITO.DAO.COLUMN:DAO-TABLE-COLUMN-CLASS {1005928483}>
--------------------
Name: BOOKSHOPS.MODELS:ISBN
Init args: (:ISBN)
Init form: #<unspecified>
Init function: NIL
--------------------
Group slots by inheritance [ ]
Sort slots alphabetically  [X]

All Slots:
[ ]  %CLASS           = #<DAO-TABLE-CLASS BOOK>
[ ]  %DOCUMENTATION   = NIL
[ ]  %TYPE            = T
[ ]  ALLOCATION       = :INSTANCE
[ ]  ALLOCATION-CLASS = NIL
[ ]  COL-TYPE         = (OR (:VARCHAR 128) :NULL)
[ ]  DEFLATE          = #<unbound>
[ ]  GHOST            = NIL
[ ]  INFLATE          = #<unbound>
[ ]  INITARGS         = (:ISBN)
[ ]  INITFORM         = NIL
[ ]  INITFUNCTION     = NIL
[ ]  NAME             = BOOKSHOPS.MODELS:ISBN
[ ]  PRIMARY-KEY      = NIL
[ ]  READERS          = (BOOKSHOPS.MODELS:ISBN)
[ ]  REFERENCES       = NIL
[ ]  WRITERS          = ((SETF BOOKSHOPS.MODELS:ISBN))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `col-type` is an extension provided by `mito.class.column:table-column-class`.  It has an accessor `%table-column-type`, which is wrapped by `mito.class.column:table-column-type`.

Comment: "of course you can't find it in the MOP documentation" Sure ! But it's a slot in my class definition, is there no generic way to access any slot details ? Am I missing mop's goal ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: You are right that this leaves some programmatic discoverability to be desired.  You could, however, try to use `(class-slots (class-of isbn-slot))`  to find the `col-type` slot, then `slot-definition-readers` and `slot-definition-writers`.  It's objects all the way down.

Comment: And sorry, I removed that sentence as it sounded much snarkier than intended.